# how to monitor RSSI of my smartphone to the router using my laptop ? (My laptop and smartphone connected to same router)

Tags: android, wireshark, wifi, indoor-positioning-system

How to monitor RSSI of my smartphone to the router using wireshark in my laptop ? (My laptop and smartphone connected to same router)